# How to get all the column names & their types, including ENUM (and it's possible values)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I wrote the following code to get all the columns names and types in sqlalchemy. However, in case of ENUM type I am getting Varchar instead.

I want to know a way using which I can get enum type for all the enum columns and all the possible values of enum as well.

```
EntityClass = eval(entity_name)
entity_dict = {}
entity_dict['attributes'] = []
for column in EntityClass.__table__.columns:
    entity_dict['attributes'].append({
        'key': str(column.key),
        'type': str(column.type).split('(')[0].split('[')[0]
    })
print entity_dict
```

I am using the following method to create a new Enum in sqlalchemy:

```
class CourseType(enum.Enum):
    Certified = "Certified"
    Non_Certified = "Non_Certified"

    @staticmethod
    def list():
        return list(map(lambda c: c.value, CourseType))
```

And this is how I am using the enum in a table:

```
type = Column(Enum(CourseType))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got the solution. This is how I solved the issue:

```
EntityClass = eval(entity_name)
entity_dict = {}
entity_dict['attributes'] = []
for column in EntityClass.__table__.columns:
    if hasattr(column.type, 'enums'):
        column_type = 'ENUM'
        possible_values = column.type.enums
    else:
        column_type = str(column.type).split('(')[0].split('[')[0]
        possible_values = 'NotApplicable'
    entity_dict['attributes'].append({
        'key': str(column.key),
        'type': column_type,
        'possible_values': possible_values
    })
return entity_dict
```

I think the str return in case of column.type was varchar only. So what I did was I checked if there was an attribute called enums in the column.type object, and if it is there I marked the column_type as ENUM and got the possible values for the column from column.type.enums.